# Elasticsearch-php queries

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Does anyone know a good resource with elasticsearch-php examples ideally covering queries taking MySQL Examples. I am struggling both with the code syntax and what to use when.

For example, I want to do a search where $name must be part of field 'business' and where 'country' matches $country

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'xxxxx',
    'type' => 'zzzzz',
    'body' => [
        'from' => 0, 
        'size' => $maxResults, 
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    'match' => ['name' => $searchString],
                ],
                'must' => [
                    'match' => ['country' => $country],
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

The first 'must' seems to be completely ignored. Removing this will return exactly the same results.

I searched around for hours. There are plenty of quick beginner tutorials with simple search examples but I already get stuck one step further like with the above example

Thanks

Comment: The elasticsearch guides do have really good examples: https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html. What we normally do is create a test in kibana, and use that json to create the php object. You can cast this object to json again and use that for your query.

Comment: Thank you, I have been reading more about this today. There a quite some examples but finding exactly what you are looking for is difficult. Testing json first will probably help and make things a little bit easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a single `must` in a `bool` query, then all must constraints must be elements of the `must` array. Try like this instead:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'xxxxx',
    'type' => 'zzzzz',
    'body' => [
        'from' => 0, 
        'size' => $maxResults, 
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                  [
                    'match' => ['name' => $searchString],
                  ],
                  [
                    'match' => ['country' => $country],
                  ],
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```